# Heroku run Jar file once deployed?

Tags: heroku, jar, heroku-cli, heroku-api

I have deployed my jar file to heroku using:

```
heroku deploy:jar <filename>.jar --app <appname>
```

Once deployed, how do I run the jar file with specific params, i.e. locally i would execute:

```
java -jar <filename>.jar <param1> <param2>
```

Am i using the Heroku service correctly? In essence I just need to run the Main command within the jar file and get the logs when completed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: does this help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733324/heroku-run-jar-file-once-deployed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
heroku deploy:jar <filename>.jar --app <appname>
```

With this you essentially hardcorded:

```
jar <filename>.jar
```

---

Here is an example where you can configure parameters for your command

https://github.com/NNTin/shell-kun/tree/6b35e4b731bcf500366f60bbceafe076bf969fe1

Note: We are looking here at older software because `HEAD` no longer has it.

You need `Procfile`. `app.json` and the Heroku Deploy (see link in `README.md`) button are optional. They make deploying easier since you don't have to touch terminal/CLI.

Essentially you extend your Procfile to:

```
web: jar <filename>.jar $ARGS_AND_FLAGS
worker: jar <filename>.jar $ARGS_AND_FLAGS
```

`web` when you are utilizing a `$PORT`, `worker` when not.

Now you can modify your command by editing the environment variable `ARGS_AND_FLAGS`.

[image]

In this case the web process is activated and the worker process is deactivated.

[image]

After you changed your environment variable you can deactivate and then activate your process.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Procfile` in the same directory where you run `heroku deploy:jar` with  the content:

```
web: java -jar <filename>.jar <param1> <param2>
```

and redeploy the app.